# Mathematical notation of bijective function

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

A function is bijective when following is true

$$ ∀  y \in   Y, !\exists  x \in X : f(x) = y.$$

How can someone read this notation?
I know it should state "All elements from Y have one element from X", but I have a hard time to read the notation (especially the $!\exists  x \in X$ part) in a mathematical way as a beginner.

And would this be the same as: 
$$ !\exists  x \in X, ∀  y \in   Y  : f(x) = y?$$

Comment: It actually reads, "all elements from Y have exactly one unique element from X such that $f(x)= y$.

Comment: The symbol ! denotes unicity. You have to read For all $y$ in $Y$ existe an unique $x$ in $X$ such that $f(x)=y$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot. And without the quantifiers? @Piquito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclamation mark indicates "unique".

Your statement is pronounced: "for all $y$ in $Y$, there is a unique $x$ in $X$ with $f(x)$ equal to $y$".

Your other statement is not the same at all. Consider $f$ the identity function (definitely bijective), and ask yourself if the statement that "there is a unique $x$ in $X$ such that for all $y$ in $X$, $x = y$" is true.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot. And without the quantifiers?